# Sums of the form $\sum_{d|n} x^d$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $$S(x,n) = \sum_{d|n} x^d, \quad n \in \Bbb N. $$

Do these sums appear in the literature? What are they called if they do and what is known about them?

---

To clarify, note that this sum is **not** the same as the generalized [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)
$$ \sigma_x(n) = \sum_{d|n}d^x.$$
The function $f(n) = n^x$ is an arithmetic function  for any constant $x$ (in the sense that $f(pq) = f(p)f(q)$ for primes $p,q$), so the method of [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) may be applied to study $\sigma_x(n)$. 
In constrast, $f(n) = x^n$ is not arithmetic when $x\neq 1$ or $0$, which suggests the functions $S(x,n)$ may require the use of other less-common techniques to understand their behavior.

Comment: possibly related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#See_also

Comment: They're called the _generalized divisor functions_. Not sure what you expect of an answer to contain; could you ask some specific questions?

Comment: Honestly, it's been quite a while since u asked the question and I am not sure exactly why I was interested in them(the bounty is not by me). I believe I needed some bounds on these functions...

Comment: I don't think the question is too broad as it stands: an ideal answer would be a precise reference with some explanation of it and would in no way be vague. In fact, as I mentioned above, I do not know the original context in which I was interested in it. I would rather not edit it to add context - I don't even know the context anymore. Looking at the number of upvotes, it seems that quite a few people are interested in it as it stands anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but here are some examples of specializations of $S(x,n)$ which do appear in the literature:

1. $S(1,n) = \sigma_0(n)$, the [number of divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) function.
2. $S(-1,n) = \#(\text{even divisors}) - \#(\text{odd divisors})$. This function sends $n = 2^v m$, where $m$ is odd, to 
   $$ S(-1,2^vm) = (-1+v)\sigma_0(m).$$
3. $S(\frac12,2^k) = \sum_{i=0}^k (\frac12)^{2^i}$, in the limit $k\to \infty$, is known as [Kempner's number](http://adamczewski.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Kempner.pdf) which is known to be transcendental (Kempner, 1916). I learned of this via [this stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587218/ordinary-generating-function-of-powers-of-2).

Question: Is it clear what happens for $S(\zeta_k,n)$, where $\zeta_k$ is a primitive $k$-th root of unity? I couldn't find a nice closed form.

Note that even though $f(n) = (-1)^n$ is not an [arithmetic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function), the sum over divisors $S(-1,n)$ is ''very close'' to being arithmetic: the formula given above shows that $-S(-1,n)$ is (weakly) arithmetic .
I'm guessing there might be some similar sense in which $S(\zeta_k, n)$ is close to being arithmetic, but it's probably too much to hope for that the same holds for $S(x,n)$ in general (as a function of $n$).