# Ordinary generating function of powers of 2

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

Is there a good closed form expression for the generating function of the formal power series
$$
A(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n} = z + z^2 + z^4 + z^8 + z^{16} + \cdots.
$$
Is there a tractable way to retrieve the coefficient of $z^m$ in powers of $A(z)$, say in $A(z)^k$ for $k \geq 1$? Thanks.

Comment: Not a closed form expression, but there is a continued fraction expression: $x / (1 - x / (1 + x / (1 + x / (1 - x / (1 + x / (1 - x / \ldots)))))$ See https://oeis.org/A209229

Comment: How could we use this to retrieve the coefficient of $z^m$ in $A(z)^k$, i.e., in powers of $A(z)$?

Comment: Almost certainly no.  It is already highly unlikely that there is a closed form for $A(1/2)$.

Answer (score 6):

The value $A(1/2)=\kappa$ is known as the Kempner number, and was proven transcendental in 1916. The paper "The Many Faces of the Kempner Number", by Adamczewski, may provide some insight for you.

Answer (score -4):

How about $A(z)=\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}$? This works if $|z|<1$.

I got this idea from expanding $\frac{1}{1-z}$.

Comment: No, you’re getting the even powers; the OP wants the exponents to be powers of $2$.

Comment: Oh I see... my fault.

Comment: You can remove your answer by clicking on the *delete* option at the bottom of your post.